# My cards in Bootstrap 4 get messed up when I add a carousel. My code for the testimonial is

Tags: bootstrap-4, alignment, carousel, card

```
<div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
      <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
      <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
      <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
      <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>

    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"> </span>
  </a>

  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"> </span>
```

When I add this code the cars all shift to the top section in a messy state. Although when I remove this the cards are fine. How to get both working fine? Any help would be deeply appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the size of the images you are using in your carousel. The width and height should be relative to the cards.
For instance, try this...

```
 <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" alt="dog-profile">
```